# Complex function with denominator $z^{33}$ .

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Evaluate $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{\log(z+2)}{z^{33}}dz$$
>   where $\gamma(t)= \exp(it)$ with $t\in [0,2\pi]$.

How can I resolve this complex integral?
I cannot differentiate the function $32$ times, I think.
Is this a polydrom function?

Comment: You just have to find the residue at $z=0$ of $\frac{\log(2+z)}{z^{33}}$. Since $$\log(2+z)=\log(2)+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}z^n}{2^n}$$ such residue is $-\frac{1}{2^{32}}$.